# How to navigate view in SwiftUI using .navigationDestination condition

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to navigate view using .navigationDestionation using Condition. or .navigationDestination cant use like that ?

```
struct SuccessfulView: View {
    enum SuccessType {
        case verifyPhoneNumber
        case setPincode
    }
    
    let successType: SuccessType
    
    @State private var moveToSetPinCode = false
    @State private var moveToMainMenu = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Image("checklist")
            
            Text("Congrats!")
                .font(.system(size: 55, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundStyle(Color("hanBlue"))
            
            Text(successMessage)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 42)
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                .foregroundStyle(Color("hanBlue"))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action :{
                if successType != .setPincode {
                    moveToMainMenu = true
                } else {
                    moveToSetPinCode = true
                }
            }) {
                Text("Great!")
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 153, height: 60)
                    .background(Color("hanBlue"))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private var successMessage: String {
        switch successType {
        case.verifyPhoneNumber:
            return "Verification has been done Successfully"
        case.setPincode:
            return "Account Registed Successfully"
        }
    }
}
```

VerifyPhoneNumberView.swift

```
struct VerifyPhoneNumberView: View {
    @State private var verifyCode = ""
    @State private var setVerify = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Please add your mobile phone number")
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 165, height: 52)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text("Enter Verification Code (5-digit)")
                .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.leading, 33)
            
            UnderlineTextFieldMain(placeholder: "56234", text: $verifyCode)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.bottom)
            
            Button {
                setVerify = true
            } label: {
                Text("Verify")
                    .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 153, height: 59, alignment: .center)
                    .background(Color("hanBlue"))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.top)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $setVerify, destination: {
                SuccessfulView(successType: .verifyPhoneNumber)
            })
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Verify your Number")
    }
}
```

I want my SuccessfulView navigate using condition.

Example Flow :
**VerifyPhoneNumberView > SuccessfulView(.verifyPhoneNumber) > SetPinCodeView > SuccessfulView(.setPinCode) > otherView.**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523285/navigationstack-programatically-appending-childviews-with-different-types/77523443#77523443) help?

Comment: no :( i have try like this: 

.navigationDestination(for: SuccessType.self, destination: { value in
                switch value {
                case .verifyPhoneNumber:
                    SetPinCodeView()
                case .setPincode:
                    AddPhoneNumberView()
                }
            })

but not work you have a clue ?

Comment: What is your current output when using `NavigationPath` and `SuccessType.self` as the destination type?

Comment: its work thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Btw, it would be great if you give an up vote xD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create state enum for selected path:

```swift
enum SignUpNavigationState: Hashable {
    case verifyPhoneNumber
    case setPinCode
    case successful(SuccessType)
    case someOtherView
}
```

Then create ViewModel with that state, it would be cleaner than using just state variable on view, but you can choose what you want:

```swift
@MainActor
class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigation: [SignUpNavigationState] = []

    func start() {
        navigation.append(.verifyPhoneNumber)
    }
}
```

And use it in the View:

```swift
struct SignUpView: View {
   @StateObject private var viewModel = SignUpViewModel()

   var body: some View {
      NavigationStack(path: $viewModel.navigation) {
          Button("Start") {
              viewModel.start()
          }
          .navigationDestination(for: SignUpNavigationState.self) { state in
              switch state {
              case .verifyPhoneNumber:
                  VerifyPhoneNumberView(viewModel: viewModel)
              case .setPinCode:
                  SetPinCodeView(viewModel: viewModel)
              case .successful(let type):
                  SuccessfulView(viewModel: viewModel, type: type)
              case .someOtherView:
                  SomeOtherView(viewModel: viewModel)
              }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

In the child views you can just append `SignUpNavigationState` on viewModel `navigation` to navigation path and it will be automatically push navigation.

For more details check out docs [NavigationStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) and [navigationDestination(for:destination:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(for:destination:))